# Problem with Function in python (TypeError: touch_detect() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given)

Tags: python, function, pytorch

im encoutnering a problem when trying to run a python code

here is the problem

```
File "touch_detect.py", line 24, in <module>
   touch_detect()
   File "touch_detect.py", line 19, in touch_detect
   is_touching, certainty = touch_detect(source.image)
   TypeError: touch_detect() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

and here is my code

```
import pytouch
from pytouch.handlers import ImageHandler
from pytouch.sensors import DigitSensor
from pytouch.tasks import TouchDetect
from pytouch import PyTouchZoo, sensors

def touch_detect():
     source = ImageHandler("/home/../Documents/Digit2.png")

     # initialize with task defaults
     pt = pytouch.PyTouch(DigitSensor, tasks=[TouchDetect])
     is_touching, certainty = pt.TouchDetect(source.image)

     # initialize with custom configuration of TouchDetect task
     touch_detect=TouchDetect(DigitSensor,zoo_model="touchdetect_resnet18")

     is_touching, certainty = touch_detect(source.image)
     print(f"Is touching? {is_touching}, {certainty}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
     touch_detect()
```

this code is actually used for tactile sensing and i'm not the one who wrote the code it was included as an example in a open source library called pytouch used for several application like touch detection which is the one i'm using

Comment: please fix your indentation

Comment: Yeah sorry ! done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the following part:

```
# initialize with custom configuration of TouchDetect task
touch_detect=TouchDetect(DigitSensor,zoo_model="touchdetect_resnet18")

is_touching, certainty = touch_detect(source.image)
```

You're calling `touch_detect` recursively with a parameter (`source.image`), but the function takes no parameters.

I suppose you want to call a method on the TouchDetect object, but the variable containing that object is named the same as the method. I would suggest using a different variable name, or changing the name of the method